# Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

how can we create table in snowflake without running create table query, directly our snowpipe will detect data format and will create a table for us.

Answer for my query related to snowflake

Comment: I don’t believe you can, why do you believe this is possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible automatically as of today.

There is a possibility to create a table for semi-structured data by using a template and inferring the file schema (this feature is currently limited to Apache Parquet, Apache Avro, and ORC files), like this example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
  USING TEMPLATE (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDER_ID)
      FROM TABLE(
        INFER_SCHEMA(
          LOCATION=>'@mystage',
          FILE_FORMAT=>'my_parquet_format'
        )
      ));
```

For more information have a look at the [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table) syntax and [INFER_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema) function.